# FFMPEG fails with seeking params before input on AWS Lambda

Tags: lambda, ffmpeg

I am trying to run the following command on AWS Lambda that has FFMPEG layer but it fails with a SIGSEGV. The FFMPEG process starts working fine until it reaches the segment's it wants to get.

```
/opt/ffmpeglib/ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00 -t 30 -i https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa-audio-only.m3u8 /tmp/out.aac -y
```

Note: The url is a sample url for this sharing

What this is doing: It will seek 2 minutes into the stream url, then capture the next 30 seconds into an out.aac file. When I run this locally, it works fine. When I run this on Lambda, it ends abruptly when reading the segments that are in the time frame I want (from 2:00min to 2:30 min).

FFMPEG will skip the frames if I put the -ss 00:02:00 -t 30 before the -i which they state is faster. If i put it after the -i, it works, but of course, it's a bit slower.

Example working command:

```
/opt/ffmpeglib/ffmpeg -i https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa-audio-only.m3u8 -ss 00:02:00 -t 30 /tmp/out.aac -y
```

Wondering if anyone knows a way to run this on Lambda. Thank you.

Note: I have tried this on Python and Javascript. Tried also making child processes with Javascript and no luck. I also added -nostdin and piped stdin/out to dev null but nothing.

Thanks.

Example of me running locally:

```
~/D/build [1]$ ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00 -t 30 -i https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa-audio-only.m3u8 /tmp/out.aac -y                                                                      14:56:13
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_audio_1_stereo_128000.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_0.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_1.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa-audio-only.m3u8':
  Duration: 00:03:31.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 128000
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 128000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_30.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x122f05250] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_31.ts' for reading
Output #0, adts, to '/tmp/out.aac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 128000
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 aac
[https @ 0x12001c600] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_32.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x124038800] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_33.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x12001c600] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_34.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x124038800] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_35.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x12001c600] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_36.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x124038800] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_37.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x12001c600] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_38.ts' for reading
size=     486kB time=00:00:30.01 bitrate= 132.8kbits/s speed=10.7x    
video:0kB audio:477kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.018663%
```

It doesn't do anything after this line via the lambda console logs:

```
[hls @ 0x72faa80] Opening 'https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/audio/1_stereo_128000/hls/segment_0.ts' for reading
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both seek methods to obtain accurate and fast result.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:59 -i input.m3u8 -ss 00:00:01 -t 30 output.aac
```